# Remove class without affecting other divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this as my jQuery

```js
$(".part-txt").click(function() {
      $('.txt-container').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 height part-txt"><span>Conversions from other tax programs</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 height">
        <div class="row checkies">
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row txt-container hide">
        <div class="col-sm-12 hide-txt">
          <p>Iusto doloribus phasellus venenatis egestas, cursus illo, perferendis, possimus eros ipsum eum saepe facilisis, nostrud ut accumsan temporibus perferendis dolorem tempora. Id risus quia neque tempora dictum, delectus irure auctor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 height part-txt"><span>Conversions from other tax programs</span></div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 height">
        <div class="row checkies">
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
         </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
            <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row txt-container hide">
        <div class="col-sm-12 hide-txt">
          <p>Iusto doloribus phasellus venenatis egestas, cursus illo, perferendis, possimus eros ipsum eum saepe facilisis, nostrud ut accumsan temporibus perferendis dolorem tempora. Id risus quia neque tempora dictum, delectus irure auctor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Basically my problem is I would like to click the .part-txt div and showing .txt-container div without affecting other divs with the same class. Sorry beginner here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** to select the next `txt-container` element related with the current clicked `part-txt`, like :

```
$(".part-txt").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.txt-container').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".part-txt").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.txt-container').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 height part-txt"><span>Conversions from other tax programs</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 height">
    <div class="row checkies">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row txt-container hide">
    <div class="col-sm-12 hide-txt">
      <p>Iusto doloribus phasellus venenatis egestas, cursus illo, perferendis, possimus eros ipsum eum saepe facilisis, nostrud ut accumsan temporibus perferendis dolorem tempora. Id risus quia neque tempora dictum, delectus irure auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 height part-txt"><span>Conversions from other tax programs</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 height">
    <div class="row checkies">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center check">
        <div class="row"><i class="fa fa-check color-dblue2"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row txt-container hide">
    <div class="col-sm-12 hide-txt">
      <p>Iusto doloribus phasellus venenatis egestas, cursus illo, perferendis, possimus eros ipsum eum saepe facilisis, nostrud ut accumsan temporibus perferendis dolorem tempora. Id risus quia neque tempora dictum, delectus irure auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find it by its parent

```
$(".part-txt").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.txt-container').toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo select as such

```
$(".part-txt").click(function() {
    $(".txt-container:first").toggleClass("hide");
});
```